# Laravel Eloquent join error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am tryng to make a join in laravel 5.1

here is my code

```
Venta::where('dbo.Venta.mov', 'some' )
                                ->where('dbo.Venta.Estatus', 'C')
                                ->join('dbo.Cte', 'dbo.Cte.Client', '=', 'dbo.Venta.Cliente')
                                ->where('dbo.Venta.Suc', '=','1')
                                ->paginate(10);
```

but i have the error:

```
SQLSTATE [42000]: [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver for SQL Server 11] [SQL Server] The 'Client' column has been specified multiple times for 'temp_table'.
```

Can somebody please help me solve this issue?

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you without knowing the schemas involved here. Clearly the query is failing with "Syntax error or access violation" but the hint about the column will only help if you can see the schemas and the temp results.

Comment: Try to specify a select clause where you will specify in which table you will get the Client column or don't exclude it in select